# How are file locks implemented in mac osx

Tags: mac-osx, permissions, filesystems

On macs you have the option of locking a file in order to prevent its deletion. But this is not done by chmodding u-w or something like that, because locked files can have write permissions. So what's the mechanism by which file locking is implemented?

Answer (score 1):

It's through the chflags command, the counterpart to [chattr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chattr).